# Ajax not working in a specific controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a MVC app that has multiple controllers. I have the following code in my js file:-

```
jQuery.ajax(
{
    url: "/Projects/AddTeamMember",
    type: "POST",
    data: { guidPersonId: personId },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        ProcessAddSpecifiedPerson(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("there");
    }
});
```

My controller goes like:-

Projects Controller :-

```
// POST: (Partial)
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AddTeamMember(Guid guidPersonId)
    {
        //dosomething
    }
```

It doesn't hit the method. Now when I change the URL to /Hr/AddTeamMember and move my method to Hr controller it works nicely.

What am i doing wrong with the project controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  jQuery.ajax(
   {
     url: '@Url.Action("AddTeamMember","Projects")',
     type: "POST",
     data: { guidPersonId: personId },
     dataType: "html",
     success: function (data) {
         ProcessAddSpecifiedPerson(data);
      },
    error: function (error) {
       alert("there");
     }
 });
```

I think your path is creating problem. Use always `Url.Action`.

Comment: No, it didn't help either.

Comment: Can you call other action in Project Controller?

Comment: No, i cant call any action method.

Comment: Rename the Project controller then it will call.

Comment: rename the project controller to?

Comment: any change that is not assembly name, project name